# How can you get access to the database with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 Online?

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2013

We currently use Microsoft Dynamics CRM v4 on-premises. Our data warehouse guys use a direct database link to get access to the data. Is this same functionality possible if you go with the CRM 2013 Online / Cloud option?

If, like I suspect that it's not, what API's are available (if any) to achieve this (or some other method)?

I've searched a lot for this but found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamics CRM Online doesn't provide direct access to the SQL database.

For interaction with the data is necessary to use the CRM Web Services, REST and SOAP endpoints.